# Display Controller Exception on view - MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json

How would I go about in returning an exception that I have caught on my controller in a try catch block to a label on the view? What would be the best way to complete this? Any code examples and explanations are welcome! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider using the TempData dictionary for this. Just keep in mind that TempData only lives for the length of the request (or until the values have been read). You could use the ViewBag (or ViewData) as well but TempData was geared for this type of scenario (and redirects like 302).

Answer (score 0):

Save it in the `ViewBag` and display the exception in the view like

in the controller

```
ViewBag.Exception = "a lot of exception";
```

in the view

```
    if(ViewBag.Exception != null) {
      ViewBag.Exception
 }
```